# How do I know if the serial cable is plugged in the right way?

Tags: serial, serial-bus, range-detector

I recently got a LeddarTech Leddar One rangefinder, which has a UART serial connector. I'm used to boards denoting the pinout directly next to the pins, but the only distinguishing mark on this board's serial connector is a small triangle pointed at the last pin (or the first pin, if you turn the board around.) Does this triangle mean the ground pin? I don't know a lot about PCB markings, and there isn't very much documentation on this product.

[image]

As you probably can figure, I don't quite want to find out firsthand what happens if I plug the cable in the wrong way.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Service manual says?

Comment: A photo might help us be more sure of the answer, but a mark in the silkscreen will usually indicate pin 1. But a "triangle"could also be a description of a ground symbol, so you could be on to something there.

Comment: Do you have an Oscilloscope so you can visually inspect which pins are data outputs? Determining which pin is the ground pin should be done by inspecting the PCB and hopefully identifying the pin(s) which are physically soldered to the ground-plane (or by referencing the manual/other online forums)

Comment: The square chip looks like an off the shelf microcontroller, you can probably lookup the pinout and figure out a lot from there.

Comment: *"there isn't very much documentation on this product"*. User manual, datasheet, application notes and whitepaper [all here](http://www.robotshop.com/en/leddartech-leddarone-optical-rangefinder-33v-uart.html). Google failed you?

Comment: @roger I'm guessing auto correct fail. To ladder.

Comment: Well, yes, there's quite a _lot_ of information on it, but I couldn't find a _picture_ explaining the orientation of the plug in respect to the board. I guess I'll try right now to plug it in and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sheet for the part labels it.

[image]

Of course, as far as I can see online, the front of the board does not have any silkscreen. But the right most pin has a square pad. This is typically pin 1. And even on the blurry picture, **its plain to see that that pin has thermal reliefs connecting it to the ground plane.** Easy bet that its ground, and the rest of the pins will match the data sheet now that you have identified it.

[image]

Comment: [The user guide](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf2/rb-led-02-04_-_54a0025-2_leddar_one_user_guide_-_2016-09-01.pdf) spells it out even more clearly. Not sure why the OP couldn't have found this with a quick Google.